# How to kill all PHP-FPM processes in a single command line

Tags: linux, process, php

I have a challenge shutting down effectively `php-fpm`; not all processes stop running and as such, `php-fpm` does not restart as expected.

I want a command line to run that will kill all the `php-fpm` process so I can add it to `init.d` so a stop will ensure they are all removed.

Below is the result of `ps -aux | grep php-fpm`;

```
793      102971  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool tokyodating.co
794      102972  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool turkeydating.co
794      102973  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool turkeydating.co
794      102974  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool turkeydating.co
795      102975  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool ukrainedating.co
795      102976  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool ukrainedating.co
795      102977  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool ukrainedating.co
796      102978  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool unemployeddating.com
796      102979  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool unemployeddating.com
796      102980  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool unemployeddating.com
822      102981  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool datingcougar.co
822      102982  0.0  0.1 4520304 5868 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool datingcougar.co
822      102983  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool datingcougar.co
798      102984  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vegandating.co
798      102985  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vegandating.co
798      102986  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vegandating.co
799      102987  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vegetariandating.co
799      102988  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vegetariandating.co
799      102989  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vegetariandating.co
800      102990  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vietnamdating.co
800      102991  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vietnamdating.co
800      102992  0.0  0.1 4520304 5888 ?        S    13:20   0:00 php-fpm: pool vietnamdating.co
720      103001  0.0  0.2 4522680 10672 ?       S    13:21   0:00 php-fpm: pool kuwaitdating.co
746      103008  0.1  0.2 4522684 10132 ?       S    13:23   0:00 php-fpm: pool newzealanddating.co
746      103009  0.0  0.1 4520304 5876 ?        S    13:23   0:00 php-fpm: pool newzealanddating.co
```

How can I kill all `php-fpm` processes running a single command line?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use killall instead, it takes a process name instead of a PID

```
killall -KILL php-fpm
```

ps: `-9` and `-KILL` are the same

Answer (score 6):

if who get problem like me:

```
-bash: killall: command not found
```

you can use:

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo ps -ef | grep php-fpm | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

I found this command here: https://gist.github.com/bmichalski/c8d25fff041a4739d6f0126edb0e9b54 , it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having issues where `killall` is not a command on your environment, I would recommend the following:

To kill all php-fpm for your user

```sh
pkill php-fpm
```

To kill all php-fpm for all users

```sh
sudo pkill php-fpm
```